# Raspberry Pico not showing text on the Waveshare Pico LCD 1.3 inch display

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I have a 2022 rpi pico W, with a Waveshare 1.3 inch display connected to it on the back [(Pico LCD 1.3)](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Pico-LCD-1.3). However, I can't get the screen to show any text. This is the code for the object:

```
from machine import Pin,SPI,PWM
import framebuf
import utime
import os
import math
# ============ Start of Drive Code ================
BL = 13  # Pins used for display screen
DC = 8
RST = 12
MOSI = 11
SCK = 10
CS = 9

class LCD_1inch3(framebuf.FrameBuffer):
    def __init__(self):
        self.width = 240
        self.height = 240
        
        self.cs = Pin(CS,Pin.OUT)
        self.rst = Pin(RST,Pin.OUT)
        
        self.cs(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1)
        self.spi = SPI(1,1000_000)
        self.spi = SPI(1,100000_000,polarity=0, phase=0,sck=Pin(SCK),mosi=Pin(MOSI),miso=None)
        self.dc = Pin(DC,Pin.OUT)
        self.dc(1)
        self.buffer = bytearray(self.height * self.width * 2)
        super().__init__(self.buffer, self.width, self.height, framebuf.RGB565)
        self.init_display()
        
        self.red   =   0x07E0 # Pre-defined colours
        self.green =   0x001f # Probably easier to use colour(r,g,b) defined below
        self.blue  =   0xf800
        self.white =   0xffff
        
    def write_cmd(self, cmd):
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(0)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([cmd]))
        self.cs(1)  

    def write_data(self, buf):
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(bytearray([buf]))
        self.cs(1)

    def init_display(self):
        """Initialize display"""  
        self.rst(1)
        self.rst(0)
        self.rst(1)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x36)
        self.write_data(0x70)

        self.write_cmd(0x3A) 
        self.write_data(0x05)

        self.write_cmd(0xB2)
        self.write_data(0x0C)
        self.write_data(0x0C)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x33)
        self.write_data(0x33)

        self.write_cmd(0xB7)
        self.write_data(0x35) 

        self.write_cmd(0xBB)
        self.write_data(0x19)

        self.write_cmd(0xC0)
        self.write_data(0x2C)

        self.write_cmd(0xC2)
        self.write_data(0x01)

        self.write_cmd(0xC3)
        self.write_data(0x12)   

        self.write_cmd(0xC4)
        self.write_data(0x20)

        self.write_cmd(0xC6)
        self.write_data(0x0F) 

        self.write_cmd(0xD0)
        self.write_data(0xA4)
        self.write_data(0xA1)

        self.write_cmd(0xE0)
        self.write_data(0xD0)
        self.write_data(0x04)
        self.write_data(0x0D)
        self.write_data(0x11)
        self.write_data(0x13)
        self.write_data(0x2B)
        self.write_data(0x3F)
        self.write_data(0x54)
        self.write_data(0x4C)
        self.write_data(0x18)
        self.write_data(0x0D)
        self.write_data(0x0B)
        self.write_data(0x1F)
        self.write_data(0x23)

        self.write_cmd(0xE1)
        self.write_data(0xD0)
        self.write_data(0x04)
        self.write_data(0x0C)
        self.write_data(0x11)
        self.write_data(0x13)
        self.write_data(0x2C)
        self.write_data(0x3F)
        self.write_data(0x44)
        self.write_data(0x51)
        self.write_data(0x2F)
        self.write_data(0x1F)
        self.write_data(0x1F)
        self.write_data(0x20)
        self.write_data(0x23)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x21)

        self.write_cmd(0x11)

        self.write_cmd(0x29)

    def show(self):
        self.write_cmd(0x2A)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0xef)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2B)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0x00)
        self.write_data(0xEF)
        
        self.write_cmd(0x2C)
        
        self.cs(1)
        self.dc(1)
        self.cs(0)
        self.spi.write(self.buffer, buf_len=self.width*self.height*2)
        self.cs(1)
# ========= End of Driver ===========

def colour(R,G,B):
# Get RED value
    rp = int(R*31/255) # range 0 to 31
    if rp < 0: rp = 0
    r = rp *8
# Get Green value - more complicated!
    gp = int(G*63/255) # range 0 - 63
    if gp < 0: gp = 0
    g = 0
    if gp & 1:  g = g + 8192
    if gp & 2:  g = g + 16384
    if gp & 4:  g = g + 32768
    if gp & 8:  g = g + 1
    if gp & 16: g = g + 2
    if gp & 32: g = g + 4
# Get BLUE value       
    bp =int(B*31/255) # range 0 - 31
    if bp < 0: bp = 0
    b = bp *256
    colour = r+g+b
    return colour
```

and this is the main block of code:

```
pwm = PWM(Pin(BL)) # Screen Brightness
pwm.freq(1000)
pwm.duty_u16(65534) # max 65535 - mid value

LCD = LCD_1inch3()
while True:
    # Background colour - dark grey
    LCD.fill(colour(0,0,0))

    # Define pins for buttons and Joystick
    keyA = Pin(15,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP) # Normally 1 but 0 if pressed
    keyB = Pin(17,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    keyX = Pin(19,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    keyY= Pin(21,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)

    up = Pin(2,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    down = Pin(18,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    left = Pin(16,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    right = Pin(20,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    ctrl = Pin(3,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    LCD.text('Hi', 120, 120, colour(255, 255, 255))
```

I've reset the pico, which didn't change anything. To my knowledge (I'm new to hardware), all the pins are set up correctly. I just can't seem to find a reason behind this issue. The buttons still work: I am able to program it so that when you press a button, the letter of that button is shown in the console, I can also change the brightness of it. But no text.

Comment: `100000_000` is how many Hz? I don't think Pico SPI can operate at that frequency. I didn't read the rest of code.

Comment: If you are going to write your own driver, read the datasheet and timing diagram carefully, your `write_cmd()` and `write_data()` toggle cs pin on every single-byte transmission which is not necessary and is not what the protocol timing diagram shown.